# Jquery accesing object internal functions from $(document)

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

So this is my code:

```
$(document).jkey('left',function(){
    alert("Left key pressed");
    $.galleryUtility.slideRight
});
```

This function is placed inside the `galleryUtility` object. The goal is to call both the `alert` and the `slideRight` function when the left key is pressed.

So far when I press the left key it calls the alert but not the `slideRight` function. I'm assuming this is because the `slideRight` is an internal function of the `galleryUtitity` object and `$(document)` is outside the scope of the object?

So how can I call `slideRight` from that function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`alert` will block all other code from running until the user interacts with the alert.

You need to switch the two lines to have your slideRight occur as you expect. An example showing `alert` blocking other JavaScript: http://jsfiddle.net/Akkuma/r8bYp/

Additionally, you aren't executing `slideRight`, which you need to do with `$.galleryUtility.slideRight()`. As a word of caution you aren't following the jQuery paradigm when it comes to plugins, which is using a string to execute a method of the plugin ie. `$.galleryUtility('slideRight')`. In fact, I'm not sure why you have galleryUtility living off of $ at all.

Comment: Just a small disclaimer: I suck at JavaScript and Jquery. Not sure if $.galleryUtility is living off $ actually. You see I put this code inside the plugin (not sure if I'm supposed to do that). That was the way the plugin used to call that same method.

Comment: There isn't really an alert in real life I just put it to illustrate that I knew the call to that function was working. Without the alert() doesn't help and putting the alert() after, it doesn't even get called at all - I guess that means that there's something wrong with the first method call?

Comment: You can't call a function without `()`. You have to try `slideRight()`. As a rule of thumb you should not be modifying other 3rd party plugins unless you want to handle merging the changes or you plan on contributing them back.

Open up Firebug's console or Chrome's console and check to see if any errors are listed. If there aren't any errors that means your code isn't doing what you think it should.

Comment: Adding () solved it! I've moved it all out of the plugin now. Thanks!

Comment: @Chaim Chaikin It would be appreciated if you'd mark the answer as accepted, since this solved it.